# Memory leak from lack of free() in this function

Tags: c, free, dynamic-memory-allocation

The following code is used to find the path of an executable for a rudimentary shell in `c`. As you can see, I dynamically allocate the `path` variable and then check to see if the path exists (via `lstat` in a helper function `cmd_exists`). I then return the path variable. My problem is, this causes a memory leak, as `path` is never freed. I can't free path before I return its value, and as of right now I can't think of any way to to release the memory that has been allocated. If anyone can help me out I'd appreciate it. Thanks

```
char * find_path(char * mypath, char * command){
     char * token = strtok(mypath, "#");
     while(token != NULL){
                         /*token size + 1 (for /) + command size*/
          char * path = calloc(strlen(token)+1+strlen(command)+1, sizeof(char));
          strcat(path, token);
          strcat(path, "/");
          strcat(path, command);
          if(cmd_exists(path) == 1){
             return path;
          }
          token = strtok(NULL, "#");
     }
     return NULL;
}
```

Comment: Where is this function used? `free` it there, after you are done with it. [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: The caller needs to free the memory, as it is now the owner.

Comment: _My problem is, this causes a memory leak, as path is never freed ?_ you can free the `path` after the function `find_path()` is called. For e.g `char *temp = find_path(x,y);` and then `free(temp)` if usage with `temp` is done.

Comment: Have the caller provide the buffer, instead of allocating it dynamically.

Comment: Returning a pointer to dynamic allocated memory is **not** by itself a memory leak. A memory leak is when there is no pointer variable that holds the address of the allocated memory. So as long a the caller saves the returned value in a pointer variable it's fine - no memory leak. But your own code do have memory leaks. Inside your while-loop you keep allocating memory and saving the address in the variable `path`. In other words - you keep overwriting the information about previously allocated memory and that is a memory leak. If you have a `calloc` in the loop you need a `free` as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's indeed one of the problems of C.  Memory ownership can be quite hard, because there are no RAII concepts (essentially, no automatic destructors) in C++.

I see 3 solutions how to solve this:

- The worst solution of the 3 is to have a global static buffer and let your find_path function fill in this buffer and return a pointer to it to the caller.  This trick is used by quite some other standard C functions, but there are also lots of problems with it (often not thread-safe, and if it is thread-safe, then the next call may overwrite the previous return value).  See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/getenv for a function that has this behavior (look at the warnings on top).
- A slightly better solution is document the return value of your function and clearly tell the caller that it is HIS responsibility to free the returned pointer.  If he doesn't you get a memory leak.  See https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/experimental/dynamic/strdup for a function that uses this behavior.
- Another solution is to have the caller pass a buffer to your function with a maximum size.  So instead of returning a `char *`, you add `char *` and `size_t` arguments (`size_t` indicating the size of the `char *` buffer in characters).  Then your find_path function can fill in this buffer.  See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strncpy for a function with this behavior.  The problem with this approach is that if the buffer is not big enough, your function needs to return a failure and the caller must pass a larger buffer.  Some Windows functions solve this by having the function returning an 'expected' buffer size, so if the call fails (because the buffer is not large enough), the caller can use the return value to see how large the buffer should be, and allocate a larger buffer.

My preferred solution depends on the actual case.  I would take the third alternative if there is a meaningful maximum buffer size (like e.g. a maximum file path).  I would take the second alternative is a maximum buffer size is difficult to predict.  In any case I would never use the first alternative.

Comment: For your first solution, you may want to use thread local storage to make it thread-safe.

Comment: In my opinion, the second option (it's the caller responsability to free) is the standart way of doing this. Just look at malloc/calloc : it return a pointer and it's your responsability to free it. Like every function that return a pointer tell you to free it (using a specific function or free), and it's logical. For the last part of your answer, if there is a meaningful maximum buffer size, why bother allocated it ? Just give a static buffer.

Comment: @Tom's - `malloc()` and `calloc()` are special cases.   There is no way within C to return (a pointer to) dynamically allocated memory of arbitrary size (in the sense of unknown to the caller until run-time), and be able to ensure it is released without making the caller responsible for releasing it.   Practically, the two common approaches I see in production code are the second and third.   Most times I see the first is code written by a beginner who does not understand dynamic memory allocation.

Answer (score 2):

You need to have `free` in two possible places.

1. You need to free the path  if `cmd_exists` returns false.
2. You need have free in caller method if `cmd_exists` returns true.

---

**1.**

```
 while(token != NULL){
                     /*token size + 1 (for /) + command size*/
      char * path = calloc(strlen(token)+1+strlen(command)+1, sizeof(char));
      strcat(path, token);
      strcat(path, "/");
      strcat(path, command);
      if(cmd_exists(path) == 1){
         return path;
      }

      free(path);   // 1. Here

      token = strtok(NULL, "#");
 }
 return NULL;
```

**2.**

```
 char *temp = find_path(...);
  .....//do your stuff
  if (temp) free(temp);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can ask the caller to free the memory:

```
// in caller
char * s = find_path("/mypath", "command");
// do something about `s`
free(s);
```